Ligdx tables and styles
This might be a bit of a generic question, but I'm kind of stomped by this.
As far as I can see there is no way to assign a style to a table, which seems odd. I mean, the use-case that you have ui-elements grouped in a table and you want the table to have a background, and that you might want different backgrounds for different such structures, seems a pretty straight-forward one.
I have taken note that I can draw background colors into a table, that I can assign images and 9-patches to their background, so there's a workaround at least, but not being able to bake this directly into your skin seems extremely tedious.
How do others handle this? Is there maybe an element that can contain a table and that can be assigned a style that I don't know about, so the background would be rendered by that element instead of the table?
EDIT:
So, it turns out that a plain Button is exactly what I described above: A styleable element that is also a table.
There is a problem with resizing, though, in which a button behaves quite differently than a table. If I set the size of a table, the table will assume that size, and content will be cut off. Which is something I'm relying on in several places.
A button, on the other hand, will blow up to fit its contents no matter what dimensions are set, and it will blow up the containing cell in the process.
Of course, this can be solved by setting the max dimensions of the containing cell. But now, if I apply a sizeTo action to the table containing the thing, the cell will keep its dimensions and the contained button will not resize.
In short, if I I set no maximum dimensions on the cell, the button will blow up and bye-bye goes the layout. If I set maximum dimensions it's fine until the outer table changes size, in which that cell will not breach its maximum size and the button does not expand to reveal the content that was previously cut off. Damned if I do, damned if I don't.
Maybe there's some configuration here that I'm missing to configure the buttons behaviour directly without involving the cell. Otherwise, I guess just setting table backgrounds independent of the skin is a much less complex way to go than opening that particular can of worms...
